# updating the record in file using c

Tags: c, file

```
case 1:
printf("enter the name of the record to be updated\n");
scanf("%s",&buf1);
fseek(p1,sizeof(s),SEEK_SET);

while(fread(&s,sizeof(s),1,p1))
    if(strcmp(buf1,s.name)==0)
    {
        printf("enter the accno,name,city,addr1,addr2,phno,accbal\n");
        scanf("%s%s%s%s%s%s%d",s.accno,s.name,s.city,s.addr1,s.addr2,s.phno,&s.accbal);
        fseek(p1,sizeof(s),SEEK_CUR);
        fwrite(&s,sizeof(s),1,p1);
        printf("the details are updated\n");
    }
break;
```

> 1. I wrote this code inside the switch case. whenever am executing this code the loop is formed.
> 2. Again and again the printf inside if condition is executed after the write function. I got confused. what is the problem??

Comment: for such a small program, you should post the whole code.. with your input file

Comment: Where does the `break` belong? Note that it does not belong to the `while` loop since you have no curly brackets `while(...){ if(...) { ... } }` and inly the `if` body will bee looped and that the while loop will be executed untill `fread(&s,sizeof(s),1,p1)` returns `0`.

Comment: its inside switch so only i used break statement

Answer (score 1):

Problems may  be these -

```
scanf("%s",&buf1);
           ^remove this (assuming buf1 is a char array you used to store string)
```

And this -

```
 scanf("\n%s%s%s%s%s%s%d\n",&s.accno,&s.name,&s.city,&s.addr1,&s.addr2,&s.phno,&s.accbal);
```

Remove `&` present in front of `s.name` `s.city` `s.addr1` and similar . Let it be in `s.accbal` as you use `%d` so it may be an integer type (As you don't show their declarations).

### Edit -

As you write this `break` is outside `if` and also loop .Try this -

```
while(fread(&s,sizeof(s),1,p1))
{
  if(strcmp(buf1,s.name)==0)
  {
    printf("enter the accno,name,city,addr1,addr2,phno,accbal\n");
    scanf("\n%s%s%s%s%s%s%d\n",&s.accno,&s.name,&s.city,&s.addr1,&s.addr2,&s.phno,&s.accbal);
    fseek(p1,sizeof(s),SEEK_CUR);
    fwrite(&s,sizeof(s),1,p1);
    printf("the details are updated\n");
    break;          //break inside block of if statement
  }
 
}
```

Comment: I changed the things but it still enter in the loop. is there any problem in fseek(p1,sizeof(s),SEEK_CUR);

Comment: ya now the loop ends , but the default block in switch is exected

Comment: @SathyaSri  Cant tell with what you have posted . These were the possible problems .Please post all relevant code.

Comment: @SathyaSri add a `break` right before the `default` block, otherwise it is a [fallthrough](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switch_statement#Fallthrough).